# $window on ngClick directive

Tags: angularjs

Why this doesn't work ?

Since angular expression doesn't have access to `window` object, i've used `$window`, however the below doesn't work.

```
<button ng-click="$window.alert('Hi There')">Hi There</button>
```

> Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like
>   window, document or location. This restriction is intentional. It
>   prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of
>   subtle bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only call services in your controllers through scope (this is the idea of separating non-UI logic from the template)

See [How to call a service function in AngularJS ng-click (or ng-change, ...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054028/how-to-call-a-service-function-in-angularjs-ng-click-or-ng-change)

$window is a service, and like other services that don't relate directly to the view, they are not accessible in the templates.

```
angular.module('app').controller('Controller', 
  ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.alert=$window.alert
}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

A template only has access to variables that are put on its `$scope`. If you need to access anything on `$window` from your template you'll need to inject `$window` into your controller and assign it to `$scope` there.

For example

```
angular.module('app').controller('Controller', 
  ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.$window = $window;
}]);
```

As pointed out in the comments, you probably don't want to expose the entire `$window` wrapper to your template so a better approach is to use a helper function on `$scope`.

```
ng-click="greet('Hi There')"

angular.module('app').controller('Controller', 
  ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.greet = function(message) {
          $window.alert(message);
      };
}]);
```

Comment: This works, but putting the whole service into the $scope is not recommended. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054028/how-to-call-a-service-function-in-angularjs-ng-click-or-ng-change for more

Comment: You're 100% correct. I assumed he was just doing this to play around with the framework and not planning to do it in production code. I could easily have assumed too much and I should have mentioned that it's not a good idea. I'll edit it in there.