# run ng-click function from console with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an interaction over a page with a following code (not mine):

```
<a id="refreshDataAction" href="#" class="Action Edit ng-scope ng-isolate-scope Tipsified" #some other code here#>
<span class="Tipsified" data-original-title="Get delivery ids from Box<br> #some other code here# ng-click="refresh()">
```

I need to activate somehow this `refresh()` function form the `ng-click` either by clicking the button, or addressing the function directly.

The standard approcach `.getElementById("x").click` does not work.

I found some solutions that play around `$scope` [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054028/how-to-call-a-service-function-in-angularjs-ng-click-or-ng-change), but they look more for usage inside the page-code itself, while I rather need a one-line approach to run it straight from the console (or, actually, addressing from VBA with `".execScript("x", "JavaScript")`).

Answer (score 0):

***ng-click*** does not trigger when you run vanilla click callback, because it's an Angular action attribute. Besides your HTML being malformed(I don't know if its on purpose), you can try this:

```
<span id="_some_id" class="Tipsified" onclick="refresh()">
```

Then:

```
getElementById("_some_id").click();
```

Comment: erm, well, didn't mentioned it clearly - this is, actually, an existing page, which I need to ineract with. So I can't make any changes to the code, I just need to addess the function ) Corrected it in the starting post

Answer (score 0):

On VBA we need to put the index number, you can try.

```
Set elem = ie.Document.getElementById("_some_id")(0)

elem.Click
```

or

```
Set elems = ie.Document.getElementById("_some_id")

For Each e In elems
    If (e.innerText = " The One") Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next e
```

Comment: Hi, Kino. As I have said: "Standart approcach .GetElimentById("x").Click does not work."